# IE "Add-on for the website failed to run" error?

Tags: java, internet-explorer

Backstory: I've got some antique HVAC equipment that still depends on an old-school Java applet on a special internal webserver (in the HVAC controller itself).  So, I have a special VM (Windows Server 2012R2 64-bit) set aside with the proper JRE (8u202 32-bit) installed and use IE11 to run it.

Suddenly about 2 months ago this quit working.  I get my login authorization prompt, but when logging in it now throws a "Add-on for the website failed to run" error.  The plug in is definitely enabled.  The security exceptions are in place.  I've done the full browser reset routine as well as removing and reinstalling the JRE.

Interestingly, I can install that version of Java on a fresh install Windows 10 Pro box (fully updated to 20H2), set my security exception, and it works fine.

What should I be looking for on that "Server" VM?  Is there any logging for plug-ins like this that I can look at?